# Web.Config transformations - O que fazer com connectionString.config se não uso Web Deploy?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deploy, web.config

Meu Web.config aponta para um arquivo de connectionString externo.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

Até aí sem novidades. O problema é que uso [Web.Config File Transformation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) 
e meu processo de deploy é em File System. Não uso Web Deploy.

Na tela de publish tenho a informação que DataBase Publish não é suportado nesse método de Publish. Resumindo não funciona com File System.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver pensei em criar um arquivo connectionString para testes, homologacao e producao. 
No meu projeto então eu teria um arquivo connectionString.config, outro chamado connectionStringProducao.config, outro connectionStringHomologacao.config e por ai vai.

E mudar na transformation como abaixo:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStringsProducao.config" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  <system.web>
   //...
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Creio que vai funcionar, mas acho que é uma gambiarra. Alguém tem uma solução melhor?

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Publicar no IIS local.

- [Instale o Web Deploy no seu IIS local](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy);
- Crie um site no seu IIS;
- Configure um arquivo de Deploy (no link tem os passos);
- Importe o arquivo criado no seu VS;
- Na parte de banco de dados, marque para não executar *Migrations*, ou para não atualizar a base (*Update Database*);
- Publique. Verifique se o arquivo `Web.config` foi transformado corretamente.